# Comparative analysis of two different periods from the data of single table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have one table in SQL Server containing locomotive failures for about two years. I am trying to create an aspx page for comparing above data on two different periods in terms of %age improvement / deterioration e.g. monthly, yearly or based on user inputs.

Table structure (`PunctualityMain`) is:

```
 ID   Date   Loco No.  Shed   Classification  loco_type   Equipt
```

I have created following stored procedure using two pivots, one for data for comparison (C= current) and another for previous data (P = previous)

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Comparative] 
     @pstrdt datetime,
     @penddt datetime, 
     @cstrdt datetime, 
     @cenddt datetime, 
     @loco_type nvarchar(255)    
AS  
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #previousdata (Equipt nvarchar(255), BSLP numeric(18,0), AQP numeric(18,0), KYNP numeric(18,0), ASNP numeric(18,0), HWHP numeric(18,0), MGSP numeric(18,0), GMOP numeric(18,0), WATP numeric(18,0),  ANGLP numeric(18,0), GZBP numeric(18,0), LDHP numeric(18,0), JHSP numeric(18,0), CNBP numeric(18,0), AJJP numeric(18,0), EDP numeric(18,0), RPMP numeric(18,0), BZAP numeric(18,0), LGDP numeric(18,0), KZJP numeric(18,0), TATAP numeric(18,0), BNDMP numeric(18,0), BKSCP numeric(18,0), SRCP numeric(18,0), BIAP numeric(18,0), BRCP numeric(18,0), BLP numeric(18,0), TKDP numeric(18,0), ETP numeric(18,0), NKJP numeric(18,0))
   CREATE TABLE #currentdata ( Equipt nvarchar(255), BSLC numeric(18,0), AQC numeric(18,0), KYNC numeric(18,0), ASNC numeric(18,0), HWHC numeric(18,0), MGSC numeric(18,0), GMOC numeric(18,0), WATC numeric(18,0),  ANGLC numeric(18,0), GZBC numeric(18,0), LDHC numeric(18,0), JHSC numeric(18,0), CNBC numeric(18,0), AJJC numeric(18,0), EDC numeric(18,0), RPMC numeric(18,0), BZAC numeric(18,0), LGDC numeric(18,0), KZJC numeric(18,0), TATAC numeric(18,0), BNDMC numeric(18,0), BKSCC numeric(18,0), SRCC numeric(18,0), BIAC numeric(18,0), BRCC numeric(18,0), BLC numeric(18,0), TKDC numeric(18,0), ETC numeric(18,0), NKJC numeric(18,0))

 INSERT INTO #previousdata SELECT   Equipt, [BSL] AS BSLP, [AQ] AS AQP, [KYN] AS KYNP, [ASN] AS ASNP, [HWH] AS HWHP, [MGS] AS MGSP, [GMO] AS GMOP, [WAT] AS WATP, [ANGL] AS ANGLP, [GZB] AS GZBP, [LDH] AS LDHP, [JHS] AS JHSP, [CNB] AS CNBP, [AJJ] AS AJJP, [ED] AS EDP, [RPM] AS RPMP, [BZA] AS BZAP, [LGD] AS LGDP, [KZJ] AS KZJP, [TATA] AS TATAP, [BNDM] AS BNDMP, [BKSC] AS BKSCP, [SRC] AS SRCP, [BIA] AS BIAP, [BRC] AS BRCP, [BL] AS BLP, [TKD] AS TKDP, [ET] AS ETP, [NKJ] AS NKJP 
 FROM 
 ( 
SELECT Equipt, Shed 
FROM PunctualityMain WHERE classification = 'Loco' AND (loco_type = @loco_type OR @loco_type IS NULL)   AND (Date >= @pstrdt OR @pstrdt IS NULL)  AND (Date <= @penddt OR @penddt IS NULL)  
 ) x
PIVOT 
( 
COUNT(Shed) 
FOR Shed IN ([BSL], [AQ], [KYN], [ASN], [HWH], [MGS], [GMO], [WAT], [ANGL], [GZB], [LDH], [JHS], [CNB], [AJJ], [ED], [RPM], [BZA], [LGD], [KZJ], [TATA], [BNDM], [BKSC], [SRC], [BIA], [BRC], [BL], [TKD], [ET], [NKJ] ))  p

 INSERT INTO #currentdata SELECT  Equipt, [BSL] AS BSLC, [AQ] AS AQC, [KYN] AS KYNC, [ASN] AS ASNC, [HWH] AS HWHC, [MGS] AS MGSC, [GMO] AS GMOC, [WAT] AS WATC, [ANGL] AS ANGLC, [GZB] AS GZBC, [LDH] AS LDHC, [JHS] AS JHSC, [CNB] AS CNBC, [AJJ] AS AJJC, [ED] AS EDC, [RPM] AS RPMC, [BZA] AS BZAC, [LGD] AS LGDC, [KZJ] AS KZJC, [TATA] AS TATAC, [BNDM] AS BNDMC, [BKSC] AS BKSCC, [SRC] AS SRCC, [BIA] AS BIAC, [BRC] AS BRCC, [BL] AS BLC, [TKD] AS TKDC, [ET] AS ETC, [NKJ] AS NKJC
 FROM 
( 
SELECT Equipt, Shed 
FROM PunctualityMain WHERE classification = 'Loco' AND (loco_type = @loco_type OR @loco_type IS NULL) AND (Date >= @cstrdt OR @cstrdt IS NULL)  AND (Date <= @cenddt OR @cenddt IS NULL)
 ) x
PIVOT 
( 
COUNT(Shed) 
FOR Shed IN ([BSL], [AQ], [KYN], [ASN], [HWH], [MGS], [GMO], [WAT], [ANGL], [GZB], [LDH], [JHS], [CNB], [AJJ], [ED], [RPM], [BZA], [LGD], [KZJ], [TATA], [BNDM], [BKSC], [SRC], [BIA], [BRC], [BL], [TKD], [ET], [NKJ] ))  p


 SELECT
 COALESCE(t1.Equipt, t2.Equipt) Equipt, NULLIF(BSLP,0) AS 'BSLP', NULLIF(BSLC,0) AS 'BSLC', CAST(((BSLP-BSLC)/NULLIF(BSLP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'BSL_I_D', NULLIF(AQP,0) AS 'AQP', NULLIF(AQC,0) AS 'AQC', CAST(((AQP-AQC)/NULLIF(AQP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'AQ_I_D', NULLIF(KYNP,0) AS 'KYNP', NULLIF(KYNC,0)   AS 'KYNC', CAST(((KYNP-KYNC)/NULLIF(KYNP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'KYN_I_D', NULLIF(ASNP,0)  AS 'ASNP', NULLIF(ASNC,0)   AS 'ASNC', CAST(((ASNP-ASNC)/NULLIF(ASNP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'ASN_I_D', NULLIF(HWHP,0)  AS 'HWHP', NULLIF(HWHC,0)   AS 'HWHC', CAST(((HWHP-HWHC)/NULLIF(HWHP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'HWH_I_D', NULLIF(MGSP,0)  AS 'MGSP', NULLIF(MGSC,0)   AS 'MGSC', CAST(((MGSP-MGSC)/NULLIF(MGSP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'MGS_I_D', NULLIF(GMOP,0)  AS 'GMOP', NULLIF(GMOC,0)   AS 'GMOC', CAST(((GMOP-GMOC)/NULLIF(GMOP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'GMO_I_D', NULLIF(WATP,0)  AS 'WATP', NULLIF(WATC,0)   AS 'WATC', CAST(((WATP-WATC)/NULLIF(WATP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'WAT_I_D', NULLIF(ANGLP,0)  AS 'ANGLP', NULLIF(ANGLC,0)   AS 'ANGLC', CAST(((ANGLP-ANGLC)/NULLIF(ANGLP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'ANGL_I_D', NULLIF(GZBP,0)  AS 'GZBP', NULLIF(GZBC,0)   AS 'GZBC', CAST(((GZBP-GZBC)/NULLIF(GZBP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'GZB_I_D', NULLIF(LDHP,0)  AS 'LDHP', NULLIF(LDHC,0)   AS 'LDHC', CAST(((LDHP-LDHC)/NULLIF(LDHP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'LDH_I_D', NULLIF(JHSP,0)  AS 'JHSP', NULLIF(JHSC,0)   AS 'JHSC', CAST(((JHSP-JHSC)/NULLIF(JHSP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'JHS_I_D', NULLIF(CNBP,0)  AS 'CNBP', NULLIF(CNBC,0)   AS 'CNBC', CAST(((CNBP-CNBC)/NULLIF(CNBP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'CNB_I_D', NULLIF(AJJP,0)  AS 'AJJP', NULLIF(AJJC,0)   AS 'AJJC', CAST(((AJJP-AJJC)/NULLIF(AJJP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'AJJ_I_D', NULLIF(EDP,0)  AS 'EDP', NULLIF(EDC,0)   AS 'EDC', CAST(((EDP-EDC)/NULLIF(EDP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'ED_I_D', NULLIF(RPMP,0)  AS 'RPMP', NULLIF(RPMC,0)   AS 'RPMC', CAST(((RPMP-RPMC)/NULLIF(RPMP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'RPM_I_D', NULLIF(BZAP,0)  AS 'BZAP', NULLIF(BZAC,0)   AS 'BZAC', CAST(((BZAP-BZAC)/NULLIF(BZAP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'BZA_I_D', NULLIF(LGDP,0)  AS 'LGDP', NULLIF(LGDC,0)   AS 'LGDC', CAST(((LGDP-LGDC)/NULLIF(LGDP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'LGD_I_D', NULLIF(KZJP,0)  AS 'KZJP', NULLIF(KZJC,0)   AS 'KZJC', CAST(((KZJP-KZJC)/NULLIF(KZJP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'KZJ_I_D', NULLIF(TATAP,0)  AS 'TATAP', NULLIF(TATAC,0)   AS 'TATAC', CAST(((TATAP-TATAC)/NULLIF(TATAP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'TATA_I_D', NULLIF(BNDMP,0)  AS 'BNDMP', NULLIF(BNDMC,0)   AS 'BNDMC', CAST(((BNDMP-BNDMC)/NULLIF(BNDMP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'BNDM_I_D', NULLIF(BKSCP,0)  AS 'BKSCP', NULLIF(BKSCC,0)  AS 'BKSCC', CAST(((BKSCP-BKSCC)/NULLIF(BKSCP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'BKSC_I_D', NULLIF(SRCP,0)  AS 'SRCP', NULLIF(SRCC,0) AS 'SRCC', CAST(((SRCP-SRCC)/NULLIF(SRCP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'SRC_I_D', NULLIF(BIAP,0)  AS 'BIAP', NULLIF(BIAC,0)   AS 'BIAC', CAST(((BIAP-BIAC)/NULLIF(BIAP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'BIA_I_D', NULLIF(BRCP,0)  AS 'BRCP', NULLIF(BRCC,0)   AS 'BRCC', CAST(((BRCP-BRCC)/NULLIF(BRCP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'BRC_I_D', NULLIF(BLP,0)  AS 'BLP', NULLIF(BLC,0)   AS 'BLC', CAST(((BLP-BLC)/NULLIF(BLP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'BL_I_D', NULLIF(TKDP,0)  AS 'TKDP', NULLIF(TKDC,0)   AS 'TKDC', CAST(((TKDP-TKDC)/NULLIF(TKDP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'TKD_I_D', NULLIF(ETP,0)  AS 'ETP', NULLIF(ETC,0)   AS 'ETC', CAST(((ETP-ETC)/NULLIF(ETP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'ET_I_D', NULLIF(NKJP,0)  AS 'NKJP', NULLIF(NKJC,0)   AS 'NKJC', CAST(((NKJP-NKJC)/NULLIF(NKJP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'NKJ_I_D',  ([BSLP] + [AQP] + [KYNP] + [ASNP] + [HWHP] + [MGSP] + [GMOP] + [WATP] + [ANGLP] + [GZBP] + [LDHP] + [JHSP] + [CNBP] + [AJJP] + [EDP] + [RPMP] + [BZAP] + [LGDP] + [KZJP] + [TATAP] + [BNDMP] + [BKSCP] + [SRCP] + [BIAP] + [BRCP] + [BLP] + [TKDP] + [ETP] + [NKJP]) AS 'TTL_P', ([BSLC] + [AQC] + [KYNC] + [ASNC] + [HWHC] + [MGSC] + [GMOC] + [WATC] + [ANGLC] + [GZBC] + [LDHC] + [JHSC] + [CNBC] + [AJJC] + [EDC] + [RPMC] + [BZAC] + [LGDC] + [KZJC] + [TATAC] + [BNDMC] + [BKSCC] + [SRCC] + [BIAC] + [BRCC] + [BLC] + [TKDC] + [ETC] + [NKJC]) AS 'TTL_C', CAST(((([BSLP] + [AQP] + [KYNP] + [ASNP] + [HWHP] + [MGSP] + [GMOP] + [WATP] + [ANGLP] + [GZBP] + [LDHP] + [JHSP] + [CNBP] + [AJJP] + [EDP] + [RPMP] + [BZAP] + [LGDP] + [KZJP] + [TATAP] + [BNDMP] + [BKSCP] + [SRCP] + [BIAP] + [BRCP] + [BLP] + [TKDP] + [ETP] + [NKJP])-([BSLC] + [AQC] + [KYNC] + [ASNC] + [HWHC] + [MGSC] + [GMOC] + [WATC] + [ANGLC] + [GZBC] + [LDHC] + [JHSC] + [CNBC] + [AJJC] + [EDC] + [RPMC] + [BZAC] + [LGDC] + [KZJC] + [TATAC] + [BNDMC] + [BKSCC] + [SRCC] + [BIAC] + [BRCC] + [BLC] + [TKDC] + [ETC] + [NKJC]))/(([BSLP] + [AQP] + [KYNP] + [ASNP] + [HWHP] + [MGSP] + [GMOP] + [WATP] + [ANGLP] + [GZBP] + [LDHP] + [JHSP] + [CNBP] + [AJJP] + [EDP] + [RPMP] + [BZAP] + [LGDP] + [KZJP] + [TATAP] + [BNDMP] + [BKSCP] + [SRCP] + [BIAP] + [BRCP] + [BLP] + [TKDP] + [ETP] + [NKJP]))*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'TTL_I_D'


 FROM #currentdata  t1
  FULL JOIN #previousdata t2 ON t1.Equipt = t2.Equipt  

 End
```

It gives me result as

```
 Equipt   BSLP  BSLC   BSL_I_D    AQP  AQC     AQ_I_D .............. 
  TM       4      5     -25.00     8    6      25.00
 VCD       1            100.00          1      
  DJ       7      2      71.42     12   28     -133.33
```

Above method is works correctly if equipment falling in both the period or atleast once in current period under any of the shed.  But it is not shown any improvement if equipment not falling in current period. Why?. Is there any method to do the same? or how to overcome this situation in present procedure?

Problem can be viewed on the following link where improvement column is remain blank for equipment 'Air Blast Circuit Breaker(DJ)' http://elocos.railnet.gov.in/Punctuality/comparative.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is in this expression:

```
CAST(((AQP-AQC)/NULLIF(AQP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))
```

When AQC is `NULL` its result is `NULL` too. BTW, you obtain the same result if AQP is `NULL`.

If you use `FULL JOIN` you need to protect your results from `NULL` values since they have meaning of `0` in your case. So use `COALESCE(ColX, 0)` everywhere in your `SELECT` statements.

UPDATE

Here is example of using `COALESCE()`:

```
INSERT INTO #previousdata
    SELECT   Equipt, COALESCE([BSL], 0) AS BSLP, COALESCE([AQ], 0) AS AQP,
. . .
```

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to understand use of COALESCE(ColX, 0) and where to put this & how. please write some code for me, if possible. thanks

Comment: @Sunil: Sorry for my incertainty. I added update to my answer which I hope answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Following modification can also be used for solve the problem as discussed above

```
CAST(((BSLP-(CASE when BSLC IS NULL then 0 else BSLC end))/NULLIF(BSLP,0)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))AS 'BSL_I_D'
```